# NaN in the context of a recursive for loop

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am trying to understand a solution I found for a problem: "You are given coins of different denominations and a total amount of money. Write a function to compute the number of combinations that make up that amount. You may assume that you have infinite number of each kind of coin."

My question is, if I run the function with change(3,[2]), why does it spit out 0. I am having trouble with comprehending how after a single recursive call currentCoin becomes undefined, and then when the program reaches the for loop in that call, it doesn't call the change function again with `total += change(amount - 0 * undefined, coins.slice(0, -1))`. Why does it not crash with either an infinite recursive call with `change(NaN,[])` or `coins.slice(0,-1)` being used on an empty array. It seems to ignore that on the for loop.

Am I misunderstanding how a for-loop works?

```js
var change = function(amount, coins) {
    if(amount == 0) return 1; 
    
    let currentCoin = coins[coins.length - 1];
    let total = 0;

    for(let qty = 0; qty * currentCoin <= amount; qty++){
        total += change(amount - qty * currentCoin, coins.slice(0, -1))
    }

    return total;
};

console.log(change(3,[2]))
```

Comment: In the case `amount` is `NaN`, the loop is never executed (`qty * currentCoin <= NaN` is always `false`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple things going on here.

First is the behavior of `coins[coins.length - 1]`. In Javascript, when you access an element of a list at an index that doesn't exist in that list, the indexer will return `undefined` instead of crashing with an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` or the like.

Second is `qty * currentCoin <= amount`. In the case that `currentCoin` is undefined (due to the above), `qty * currentCoin` will be `NaN`. In Javascript, any comparison of `NaN` with another number will return false by design. (e.g. `NaN <= anything` is false).

Put this all together and you see that, on the first recursion, the `coins` array will be empty which makes `currentCoin` NaN. This causes `qty * currentCoin <= currentAmount` to be false, which causes the loop to short circuit (so `slice` never gets called on an empty list). Since the loop never executes, `total` will still be 0, which is what gets returned. This continues until `qty * currentCoin <= amount` becomes true in the outermost recursion, and that loop exits with `total` still equalling 0 (since it only ever added 0).

If you intersperse `console.log` calls in strategic places about the function, it becomes clearer what is happening:

```js
var change = function(amount, coins) {
  console.log(amount, coins);
  if(amount == 0) return 1; 

  let currentCoin = coins[coins.length - 1];
  console.log(':', currentCoin, amount);
  let total = 0;

  for(let qty = 0; qty * currentCoin <= amount; qty++){
    total += change(amount - qty * currentCoin, coins.slice(0, -1))
    console.log('=', total);
  }

  console.log('recdone');
  return total;
};

console.log(change(3,[2]))
```

Comment: Ok thanks to everyone I understand now that the for loop short circuits at qty * currentCoin when currentCoin in NaN. But isn't qty = 0 an initializer, so that it is executed once before qty * currentCoin is processed. Or does javascript read through the entire for loop first under the hood, and then executes qty = 0? That is my big confusion.

Comment: Yes, `qty = 0` does initialize `qty`.  Because this is declared with `let`, the scope for that variable is just the `for`-loop block, but even if it were more global, it doesn't matter because `qty` is not going to be used anywhere.

Comment: The `for`-loop syntax is somewhat odd.  `for(initialization; condition; increment) body` runs in this order: `initialization -> (condition(T) -> body -> increment) * -> condition(F)` where that inner loop of `condition -> body -> increment` runs repeatedly until `condition` returns something false-y.

Comment: @jkidd22 In virtually every C-like language (Javascript included), a for loop's structure is `for (initializer; condition; post-op) body` and the execution goes like this: `initializer => condition => body => post-op => condition => body => post-op => condition => body => ...` for as long as the condition is true. If at any point the condition is false, execution breaks there, which means the earliest it could break is after the initializer is run and the condition is checked for the first time. (This is not to be confused with the syntactically similar but semantically different foreach loop)

Comment: @jkidd22 In this case, that means `let qty = 0` and `qty * currentCoin <= amount` are guaranteed to run (in that order), but the `qty++` and the body of the loop are not.

Answer (score 0):

not crash because a NaN in comparison with a number is every false...
NaN < number or NaN > number and so on produce false... so the

```
qty * currentCoin <= amount
```

is evaluate false and will exit from the for.

So, if you need to check the NaN you must before the for

```
let totalCoin = qty * currentCoin;
let check = isNaN(totalCoin);
if(check) {
  // return you sentinel value;
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that, in this particular case, the NaN check is unnecessary since a value of NaN will cause the loop to short-circuit and the function to return the correct result.

Comment: As said in my comment "So, if you need to check the NaN you must before the for"... IF you need, means that i don't know the logic used by the way, and i don't want to know that...

I know that, as i said, the conditional written is always false so broke and exit the cycle..

Answer (score 0):

```
var change = function(amount, coins) {
    if(amount == 0) return 1; 
    
    let currentCoin = coins[coins.length - 1]; // firstpass 1-1 = 0, second pas 0-1=-1 => coins[-1] = undefined 
    let total = 0;
                   // this will 0*0<=3, second pass 0*undefined => null which is false hence never execute      
    for(let qty = 0; qty * currentCoin <= amount; qty++){
        total += change(amount - qty * currentCoin, coins.slice(0, -1))
    }

    return total;
};

console.log(change(3,[2]))
```

In second pass when coins.length = 0 then

```
let currentCoin = coins[0 - 1]; // = undefined
```

Later in for loop you will 0 * undefined ( qty * currentCoin) which results NaN which is Not a number

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for recursion in this case. One can use a bottom-up dynamic programming approach. Let `ways[i]` denote the number of ways to get to `i` dollars with the given coins and `coins[i]` represent the value of the `i`th coin. Then, `ways[i]` is the sum of all `ways[i - coins[j]]` for all `j` from 1 to the number of coins.

```js
var change = function(amount, coins) {
    const ways = Array(amount + 1);
    ways[0] = 1;
    for(const coin of coins){
      for(let i = coin; i <= amount; i++){
        ways[i] = (ways[i] ?? 0) + ways[i - coin] ?? 0;
      }
    }
    return ways[amount];
};
console.log(change(5,[1,2,3,4,5]))
```

Comment: OP isn't trying to find an optimal solution to the coin problem. They are trying to understand how a specific solution they found works.

Comment: @Abion47 I see. I will leave the answer here in case someone else finds it useful.